> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more detail BUILD FAILED

Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED


Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[x86]

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
e: file:///C:/Users/Hermon/ProductDelivery/android/app/src/main/java/com/productdelivery/MainApplication.kt:26:58 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Hermon/ProductDelivery/android/app/src/main/java/com/productdelivery/MainApplication.kt:28:50 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Hermon/ProductDelivery/android/app/src/main/java/com/productdelivery/MainApplication.kt:29:49 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Hermon/ProductDelivery/android/app/src/main/java/com/productdelivery/MainApplication.kt:38:9 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details

BUILD FAILED in 31s
i'm using gradle-8.5-all.zip now
when i tried to run my build. i got this error. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

how should i resolve this?. even i tried updating the gradle version from 8.5 to 8.8 it showed up this error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductDelivery\android.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-01d4e30e-b9a4-4c2a-8c08-78ef21e6ab78) to immutable location (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductDelivery\android.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductDelivery\android.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-01d4e30e-b9a4-4c2a-8c08-78ef21e6ab78) to immutable location (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductDelivery\android.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)

what i want to do to get the build successful

This question is similar to: unresolved reference : BuildConfig in Kotlin. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
